# How should I implement OAuth for an application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am creating an application for a client that needs to do the following:

- Allow users to authenticate using Google, Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn.
- Allow users to add additional providers after signing up. (i.e. if the user authenticated with Google then they should be able to add any or all of the other providers as well.)
- Allow users to import Google contacts, Facebook friends list, twitter followers, and Linkedin friends in order to build a custom contact list.

Where is the best place to start learning about this? Is there a standard that everybody uses for these things in .NET? I've been Googling around for a few hours and while it seems most people point to [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) I can't seem to find any solid tutorials on how to use the library. The download comes with samples but it's still confusing me.

I assumed it would be as simple as:

- Configure providers' secrets.
- Begin login with provider
- Authenticate user with auth cookie
- Create user record in my database and store unique ID from provider.

But it seems like every provider has it's own set of code and it's all so different and confusing. Facebook has some graph object, twitter has some "InMemoryTokenManager" that I don't understand, and Google doesn't even have an authentication example, only a Google Address Book example. And on top of all that you have to copy bits of code out of some ApplicationBlock demo in the samples into your own app for some reason, and getting that all to compile without knowing what the heck it's trying to do is an arduous task.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental with all this.

Even a book recommendation would be great at this point.

I believe I understand the high-level concepts of OAuth but once I try to dive into the nitty-gritty I immediately get lost.

Comment: See this vedieo : http://www.slideshare.net/leahculver/implementing-oauth

Comment: Unfortunately, the variation in degree of how you'd like to implement each Social Networks API will vary.  However, most of them use a form of O'Auth with a Token to actually connect.

Comment: I just wish there were some simple tutorials for DotNetOpenAuth. Every SO question that asks for such documentation inevitably gets told to "download the samples, that's all you need". For apparently dumb people like me, the samples are not "all you need".

Comment: I would check the O'Auth Official Web-Site.  Also, I'd look into a book on O'Auth for Social Networks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is really no point in using external libraries if you are on net 4.5 where the default asp.net template comes with authentication code for most of these mentioned providers.

Second, if you still need a good tutorial on some details of oauth2 authentication, take a look at this great post by Ben Foster http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/oauth-providers

Third, unfortunately, if you need anything else than authentiation, there is no single protocol. Thus, each provider has its own way of exposing these additional data - contacts, posts etc. You can't do much about it, it has nothing to do with oauth2 but is just a way of invoking a specific api which by chance is often exposed as rest/xml web services based on oauth2 authentication. This means that if you do authentication only, the protocol is mostly the same for each provider. Anything more is specific.

Fourth, I would stick with the email address returned by a provider rather than internal id. Not all providers support the id whereas all of them can return user email. And you can trust this information as providers verify emails before they return it via oauth2.

Comment: Twitter doesn't seem to return email and there doesn't seem to be an option to even ask the user for it.

Comment: @AlexFord: thanks for this comment. I always do oauth2 to google/facebook/live and the lack of email from twitter is something new to me. Consider my last remark invalid but others hold.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use World Domination from PureKrome, it's trivial to use, well documented and very nice!

https://github.com/PureKrome/WorldDomination.Web.Authentication

It handles Twitter, Google, Facebook et al with simple one line configurations, and it handles everything else.

The creator hangs around n jabbr.net a lot as well.

Comment: Hahaha I love the README. Will this help me do more than just authenticate? I need to grab users' friends/contacts as well at some point.

Comment: No, it won't do that - afaik that's nothing to do with OAuth, that would be bespoke for every service you want to grab that data from.

Comment: Btw, took me 5 minutes to hook WD into an existing application :) just store the token in a table linked to the user account (I store provider name, token and then the raw return from the provider as well, you never know when you might need it...) and set the asp.net Auth token cookie manually.

Comment: I'll definitely have a closer look at this. Maybe if I standardize the authentication with something simple like this then I can roll my own wrapper for the rest of each provider's API since they're all so different anyway. I hate reinventing the wheel, but it seems writing my own wrapper may be the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET MVC 4 'Internet Application' template has `DotNetOpenAuth` implemented on it, you should take a look at that if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah I've seen that. I can't seem to find any examples of it without tight integration with the default membership and roles provider. This application doesn't use that. It does `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId)` and then uses `User.Identity.Name` to later get access to `userId`. After that it's all custom data model.

Comment: Then you'll probably need to look at rolling your own implementation of `SimpleMembershipProvider`.

Comment: Figured as much. I've really been trying to avoid that, but if there's no other way. Is the built-in functionality extensible? Can I add LinkedIn into the mix?

Comment: If you've already implemented your own MembershipProvider, all that code should carry straight over to SimpleMembershipProvder.  You'll just have to manage the additional tables required by OAuth.  The external authentication implementation isn't specific to any particular site, so it should be very simple to add LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Social Bootstrap API](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/timelines) project (it uses servicestack, but it's nice to see all of those buzzword technologies working together in a readable sample).

Also, if you want to get a better handle on how OAuth works, [Mashape has good explanation](https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth/blob/master/FLOWS.md#sources).  That will give you a look at the behind the scenes stuff that most wrappers implement.

[Rick Strahl has an example](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth) that I used years ago to implement OpenID in MVC.  It's a bit dated but it was one of the most straight forward implementations at the time.  Several customer sites that I built with that implementation are still running fine.